# Printing entire solution from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to find a way to print out my entire solution (all source code) from Visual Studio 2013 at once. I know I can print individual classes one at a time, but that seems a little too slow when my entire solution is pretty large. I've tried macros but I haven't had any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that was deprecated in the early 80's